# How do i catch status code with httpClient angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working with http client i have a in my service

```
  private extractData(response: HttpResponse<Truck>) {
    const body = response;
    return body || {};
  } 

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage: string;

    // A client-side or network error occurred.
    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    }
  ,
    else {
      errorMessage = `server side  ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`;
    }

    console.error(errorMessage || err);
    return Observable.throw(err.status);
  }
```

and a create method post

```
createTruck(truck: Truck): Observable<number> {
     return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, JSON.stringify(truck), {headers: this.headers})
      .pipe(
        map(this.extractData),
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

In my component im trying to get the status code ,the method succesfully posts but i have errors when i try a duplicate truckCode which i want to be returned as a message in the app.

```
processForm() {

    this.processValidation = true;
    if (this.truckForm.invalid) {
      return; //Validation failed, exit from method.
    }

    // if we are here then all good
     this.preProcessConfigurations()

    let truckCode = this.truckForm.get('truckCode').value.trim();
    let date = this.truckForm.get('date').value.trim();
    let description = this.truckForm.get('description').value.trim();


    if (this.truck.truckId == undefined) {
      let truck= new Truck(null, truckCode, date, description);

      this.truckService.createTruck(truck).subscribe((truck) => {
        console.log(truck);
        this.router.navigate(['/trucks'])
      },
        errorCode => this.statusCode = errorCode);

    }else {
      let truck= new Truck(this.truck.truckId, truckCode, date, description);

      this.truckService.updateTrucks(truck).subscribe((truck) => {
        console.log(truck);
        this.router.navigate(['/trucks'])
      }, errorCode => this.statusCode = errorCode);

    }
  }
```

so in my html i did this to get the status code but it doesnt work, i i think there is a problem with the service as it maps the body and not a status code what can i do ? here is my html part of it

```
           <!--form end-->
            </form>
            <br/>
            <div *ngIf="statusCode; else processing">

              <div *ngIf="statusCode === 201" [ngClass] = "'success'">
                Article added successfully.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="statusCode === 409" [ngClass] = "'success'">
                Article already exists.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="statusCode === 400" [ngClass] = "'success'">
                Article already exists.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="statusCode === 200" [ngClass] = "'success'">
                Article updated successfully.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="statusCode === 204" [ngClass] = "'success'">
                Article deleted successfully.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="statusCode === 500" [ngClass] = "'error'">
                Internal Server Error.
              </div>
            </div>

            <ng-template #processing>
              <img *ngIf="requestProcessing" src="assets/images/loading.gif">
            </ng-template>
          </div>
```

the #processing part works but status code doesnt any help please thank you.

How it looks now , after i added it gave error status does not exist on type truck, what could it b

```
e

  this.truckService.createTruck(truck).subscribe((truck) => {
    console.log(truck['_body']);
    this.router.navigate(['/trucks'])
  }, this.statusCode = truck.status;
    // (errorCode: Response) => { this.statusCode = errorCode.status})
    // errorCode => this.statusCode = errorCode); 
  this.truckService.updateTrucks(truck).subscribe((truck) => {
    console.log(truck['_body']);
    this.router.navigate(['/trucks'])
  },this.statusCode = truck.status;
    // (errorCode: Response) => { this.statusCode = errorCode.status});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the error first to Response-object.
Then you can access the error code.

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

if (this.truck.truckId == undefined) {
  let truck= new Truck(null, truckCode, date, description);

  this.truckService.createTruck(truck).subscribe((truck) => {
    console.log(truck);
    this.router.navigate(['/trucks'])
  },
    (errorCode: Response) => { this.statusCode = errorCode.status });

}else {
  let truck= new Truck(this.truck.truckId, truckCode, date, description);

  this.truckService.updateTrucks(truck).subscribe((truck) => {
    console.log(truck);
    this.router.navigate(['/trucks'])
  }, 
     (errorCode: Response) => { this.statusCode = errorCode.status });

}
```

This should do.

Comment: i did that now and in my console i still get truck.service.ts:95 server side  400, body was: IllegalStateException: such Truck already exits

Comment: Wait! You use this code fragment with both subscriptions! Did you change both parts in your code? I mean *this.truckService.createTruck(truck).subscribe()* and *this.truckService.updateTruck(truck).subscribe()*

Comment: I edited / updated my example. Now both subscriptions are covered.

Comment: yes i actually still the same error   check my error handler and extractData its ok that i am return the body ?

Answer (score 1):

I did that by simply:

In your truckService:

```
import { map, tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

...

        createTruck(truck: Truck): Observable<number> {
         return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, JSON.stringify(truck), {headers: this.headers})
          .pipe(
            map(this.extractData),
            tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
            catchError(this.handleError));
      }
```

In your component:

```
processForm() {

  this.processValidation = true;
  if (this.truckForm.invalid) {
    return; //Validation failed, exit from method.
  }

  // if we are here then all good
   this.preProcessConfigurations()

  let truckCode = this.truckForm.get('truckCode').value.trim();
  let date = this.truckForm.get('date').value.trim();
  let description = this.truckForm.get('description').value.trim();


  if (this.truck.truckId == undefined) {
    let truck= new Truck(null, truckCode, date, description);

    this.truckService.createTruck(truck).subscribe((truck) => {

      this.router.navigate(['/trucks']);
    },
    error => {
      if(error){
        this.statusCode=error;
        console.log('error code'+ this.statusCode)
      }
    });

  }else {
    let truck= new Truck(this.truck.truckId, truckCode, date, description);

    this.truckService.updateTrucks(truck).subscribe((truck) => {

      this.router.navigate(['/trucks']);
    },
    error => {

        if(error){
          this.statusCode=error;
          console.log('error code'+ this.statusCode)
        }

    });

  }
}
```

> Edit: Better approach that works. Get that in your `subscribe` and
>   assign it to the variable you want. Leaving error just for logging,
>   that way you can use data you retrieve. `error` is used for
>   errorHandling, not passing data. That you will do on `.subscribe`.

You can see that this way you are receiving a full Response with everything you need, like headers, ok, status, statusText, type, url and _body.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

So everything was ok except that this is angular 4 and in the static method throw doesnt come with the import of rxjs/Observable, this was the problem

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse| any) {
    let errorMessage: string;

    // A client-side or network error occurred.
    if (error.error instanceof Error) {
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${error.error.message}`;

    } else {
      errorMessage = `server side  ${error.status}, body was: ${error.error}`;
    }

    console.error(error.ok || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.status);// observable throw is not a function 
  }
```

you to explicitly do import

```
 import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

with this it will now work

Comment: Observable.throw is now deprecated